# Compare Value and Transfer Column in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this sub in Excel 2010 that transfers columns from other sheets and inserts it into a table. The new table has 7 columns. The first 5 are just copying right from the other sheets and they work fine.  The last two, however, are supposed match  the Program Number from the new table against the Program Number in one of two other sheets and copy the column from there. These are the two that don’t work. It doesn’t throw any errors, the columns just don’t populate.

This is the excerpt that isn’t working. I’m quite new to VBA in excel so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Sub Program_List()

```
Dim SiteNoTransfer As String
Dim SiteNo As String

Dim TransferCol(7) As Integer

Dim Row As Integer
Dim RowTransfer As Integer
Dim StartColumn As Integer

Dim rSrc As Range
Dim rDst As Range

TransferCol(0) = 0      'Nothing (placeholder)
TransferCol(1) = 10     'Proj No, from Data
TransferCol(2) = 1      
TransferCol(3) = 3      
TransferCol(4) = 11     
TransferCol(5) = 15     
TransferCol(6) = 10   'From Sheet 1 or 2
TransferCol(7) = 17   'From Sheet 1 or 2

StartColumn = 45 
Row = 7         


Do While True
    SiteNo = Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn - 11)
    If SiteNo = "" Then
        Exit Do
    ElseIf Not SiteNo = "" Then
        RowTransfer = 4
        Do While True
            SiteNoTransfer = Worksheets("Data").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(1))
            If SiteNoTransfer = "END" Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf SiteNoTransfer = SiteNo Then
                Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
                Worksheets("Data").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(1)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 255)

                For i = 1 To 4
                    If Not TransferCol(i) = 0 Then
                       Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Worksheets("Program").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(i))
                    End If
                Next

                For i = 5 To 5
                    If Not TransferCol(5) = 0 Then

                  Set rSrc = Sheets("Data").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(5))
                  Set rDst = Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i)

                  rDst = rSrc
                  rDst.NumberFormat = "yyyy"

                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Next
         'Where the code stops
                For i = 6 To 6
                    If Not TransferCol(6) = 0 Then
                        If Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, TransferCol(1)) Then
                            Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(6))
                        End If
                    ElseIf Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1) = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells(Row, TransferCol(1)) Then
                            Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(6))
                        End If

                Next

                For i = 7 To 7
                    If Not TransferCol(7) = 0 Then
                        If Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1) = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Row, TransferCol(1)) Then
                            Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(7))
                        End If
                    ElseIf Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1) = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells(Row, TransferCol(1)) Then
                            Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells(RowTransfer, TransferCol(7))
                        End If

                Next

            End If
            RowTransfer = RowTransfer + 1
        Loop
    End If

    Row = Row + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

EDIT: This is about what the sheets look like.

```
Sheet 1

| Project No. | Col 2 |... | Col 6 | Col 7

+------------+---------+-------+---------+

| 12-3456 | Date|... | 1234| 0987

+------------+---------+-------+---------+

| 22-3456 |Date|...| 2234 | 9876

+------------+---------+-------+---------+

Sheet 2

| Project No. | Col 2 |... | Col 6| Col 7

+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------

| 32-3456 | Date |... | 3234 | 8765

+------------+---------+-------+---------+------------+


Results

| Project No. | Col 2 |... | Col 6 | Col 7 

+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------

| 12-3456 | Date |... | 1234 | 0987

+------------+---------+-------+---------+------------+

| 22-3456 | Date |... | 2324 |  9876

+------------+---------+-------+---------+------------+

| 32-3456 | Date |... | 3234 |  8765
```

So to clarify, in case this is still messy, if the Project Number matches Sheet1, then it takes column 6 from Sheet1, and the same for column 7.

Comment: Okay, it will be helpful if you can edit your questions to include what your columns look like and what is to be copied and what the result should look like.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But if you could clarify, I'd be more than happy to.

Comment: Your for loops look wrong... should be For i = **1** To 6

Comment: Loops 1-4, and 5 are accounted for earlier in the code. Those work, so I didn't post them. Only 6 and 7 aren't working.

Comment: @AxxieD What I mean is adding the columns to show what you are doing. Something like in the bottom part of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852717/macro-to-replace-pre-existing-number/24853613#24853613

Comment: @CaptainABC I added the columns. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up doing this with VLOOKUP. So it looked something like:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC,'GROUP1'!A:O,6, FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC,'GROUP2'!A:O,6, FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Much clearer now and thanks for posting the columns. It appears as if though your `If` statement is returning "False" value and that's why the column is not populating.

However, I think you will need to post more of your code as it is currently not possible to debug it without knowing the values of Row, StartColumn, & RowTransfer.

But your code aside for a second, let me see if I understand correctly:

- You check if the "Project Number" in A2 of the results sheet is matching the "Project Number" of A2 in Sheet1. If not then you check A3, A4, A5 of Sheet1 until you find a match.
- If no match is found you start looking the same way in Sheet2.
- Once the match is found, let say in A5 of Sheet1, you take the values of Columns 2-7 of the corresponding row in Sheet1 and copy them to the row with the same "Project Number" in the results sheet.

Please confirm if I understand you correctly so maybe a I can try and put together a code. Also, it would be helpful if you explain what is the reason for having 2 sheets (Sheet1 & Sheet2) as opposed to having just 1.

Comment: All I want it to check is the one column. If it doesn't match A2 in Sheet 1, I want it to go look in Sheet 2 right away. If it finds a match in Sheet 1, then it pastes column 6/7 depending on which itteration. If it doesn't, then it looks in Sheet 2 and pastes that column. I'm not sure if I'm making it any clearer. I'll post the entire code, hopefully that'll make more sense. The reason there's two separate sheets is because some projects are from one group and some are from another. So each sheet corresponds to a group.

Comment: @AxxieD Thanks. But are you pasting the whole column or just value of the column corresponding to the found row?

Comment: Just the value - which I realize, looking at it, it doesn't appear I wrote my if to do.